# Trying to sort result obtained from Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Step 1: I am using entity to get the result. I run a query like this

```
Dim inbox = From p In dbContext.Inboxes Where p.RecordId = member_id Select p
```

Step 2: After that I put that into

```
Dim inboxList As IEnumerable(Of Entities.Inbox) = inbox.ToList()
```

so somewhere between step 1 and 2 I need to sort the List like so

```
inbox.OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.Importance) <-- PROBLEM HERE
```

The above line seems to have results, no exceptions, it just does not do anything!?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by will return a re-arranged value it won't actually rearrange itself.

You want:

```
inbox = inbox.OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.Importance)
```

Without assigning an output to a variable, it won't do anything

Comment: DUH :) Thank you @Dan Drews